# android 12, how replace the notification trampolines

Tags: android-notifications, android-12

Having android sdk which intercept the push notification, and has been using notification trampoline to further open the end activity. In the case of deeplink the app who uses this sdk will open the configured deeplink handler activity.

Snippet for the `trampoline`:

```
public class NotificationTrampolineReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        final PendingResult asyncResult = goAsync();
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        asycTask(executor, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String urlStr = getStringExtra(intent, PUSH_URL);
                if (urlStr != null) {
                    var intent2: Intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlStr));
                    if (intent2 != null) {
                        intent2.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        intent2.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
                        context.startActivity(intent2);
                        logAnalytics(intent, Message.MessageAction.OPEN);                   
                     }
                }
                asyncResult.finish();
            }
        });
    }

    void asycTask(ExecutorService executor, final Runnable task) {
        try {
            executor.execute(task);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {}
    }
}
```

[The `notification trampolines` is not working in Android 12 anymore](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#notification-trampolines).
The notification trampolines is needed in the sdk to intercept the click and do something like to log analytics event; closing the notification drawer when clicking at the `Action` button on the notification, etc. And this sdk does not know what activities the app may configure to handle the deeplinks.

Using a dummy activity to replace the `trampoline` would work, but not feel right, i.e. open the activity and inside to open another one then finish this one.

When android 12 puts restriction on the `notification tramoline`, does it suggest a replacement for the use case like the one here? Haven't find one.

What is the suggested new solution for intercepting the push notification tap first and then open the activity?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are better off launching an `Activity` directly from the `Notification`. The `Activity` could then do the analytics and figure out what `Activity` needs to be launched and then delegate to that. As an alternative, the launched `Activity` could send the broadcast `Intent` to your `BroadcastReceiver` which could do the work.

NOTE: If you launch an `Activity` directly from a `Notification`, that **is not a trampoline**. The trampoline occurs when you launch a `Service` or a `BroadcastReceiver` directly from the `Notification` and **that component** then launches an `Activity`. The idea is that the user needs to be in control of what pops onto his screen. If he taps a notification, he expects that something will appear on his screen, if your `Service` launches an `Activity`, that can happen at any time and could possibly interrupt him.

Comment: Hello I am unable to receive data payload in MainActivity's onNewIntent() method. i need to capture data that data and pass to web server

Comment: @VasudevM.Vyas You should open a new question for this. Asking this here as a comment to an answer won't get enough attention for your problem.

Comment: Hi @DavidWasser, In my case I want to open GoogleMap and wanna track the notification open event. I tried a hack to call a transparent activity. In that, I added a code to track the Notification open event & then called GoogleMap. But the issue is: When my app is in the background then only the scenario works correctly but when I remove it from the background I get an `Indirect notification activity start (trampoline)` error.

Comment: @KavitaPatil Can you please open a new question for this? I also don't understand what you mean when you say "when I remove it from the background I get an ... error". Please open a new question add more details about this error and I'll be happy to look at it.

Comment: @DavidWasser thank you so much for this - I wish the IDE could give hints, I couldn't find anything in logcat or see any exceptions -  I just had the notification action buttons doing nothing and closing the notification. I moved my action click logic from the receiver class to the class .building() the notification and it finally opened the activity :D