# android, what would be the use case for one Pendingintent to launch multiple activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

```
public static PendingIntent getActivities (Context context, 
                int requestCode, 
                Intent[] intents, 
                int flags)
```

[In the doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#getActivities(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%5B%5D,%20int)) , it says the intent[] is "Array of Intents of the activities to be launched."

It seems to be used for the case of launching multiple activities.

Could not think of a use case that multiple activities to be opened through a notification tap.  Anyone has a sample  for showing to launch multiple activities through one Pendingintent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#startActivities(android.content.Intent%5B%5D,%20android.os.Bundle)) for `startActivities()` (which is what this eventually ends up doing) explains what happens pretty clearly:

> Launch multiple new activities. This is generally the same as calling
> `startActivity(android.content.Intent)` for the first `Intent` in the
> array, that activity during its creation calling
> `startActivity(android.content.Intent)` for the second entry, etc. Note
> that unlike that approach, generally none of the activities except the
> last in the array will be created at this point, but rather will be
> created when the user first visits them (due to pressing back from the
> activity on top).

So you would use this if you want to launch a specific `Activity` in an app and you want to make sure that the activity stack is set up appropriately, so that when the user presses BACK, it would cycle back through the stack of activities that you set up.

Personally, I understand what they were trying to do here, but I think it is a major fail and there are better ways of doing this (basically having your app be smart enough to understand how to get you back to the previous `Activity` without assuming that it is present in the stack). But that's just my un-asked-for opinion.

Comment: Thanks @David Wasser! you help is always appreciated. I was looking for the replacement for "tramplione" restricted in android 12 (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#notification-trampolines), and thought maybe this getActivities() might be the solution, i.e. one intent for the real activity, and one intent for dummy.  Not sure if it would work, or there is better/suggested way.

Comment: The trampoline restriction is to prevent activities from being started by background components (`Service`, `BroadcastReceiver`). If you want an `Activity` started by a `Notification`, then you should launch the `Activity` directly from the `Notification`. I'm not sure what you are trying to do here by starting multiple activities. Can you give more details?

Comment: we used to have the "tramplione" - a BroadcastReceiver to handle the tap on the notification, in the Receiver it will figure out what activity to launch and does the proper analytics log etc. So this will not work on android 12 anymore. Thinking to change to using one PendingIntent with multiple Intents (one for the real activity to launch, the other is a dummy activity for doing the log etc. stuff - because we are a lib/sdk dont always own the launched activity, i.e. in deeplink case, or simply a Intent.ACTION_VIEW with url case).

Comment: No, this won't work. If you use a `PendingIntent` with multiple `Intent`s, only the last one actually gets launched. The others are inserted into the task stack, but they will not get launched until launched `Activity` finishes (and depending on how the launched `Activity` finishes, it may or may not result in the other activities being launched.

Comment: You are better off launching an `Activity` from the `Notification`. The `Activity` could then so the analytics and figure out what `Activity` needs to be launched and then delegate to that. As an alternative, the launched `Activity` could send the broadcast `Intent` to your `BroadcastReceiver` which could do the work.

Comment: Thanks David for share your opinion! Yes the current try I have is the notification tap launches a dummy activity which will be finished immediately after it does the analytics log etc. and launched the target activity, which is just replacement of the Receiver. The only concern is isnt it still a "tramplione"?
The other thought is here to give PendingIntent two activities, the 1st is the target and the last is the dummy, after the dummy finished (from inside the onCreated()), the os's call stack management will show the target activity. Feel it is better, but hav not tried out throughly.

Comment: If you launch an `Activity` directly from a `Notification`, that is **not a trampoline**. The trampoline occurs when you launch a `Service` or a `BroadcastReceiver` directly from the `Notification` and that component then launches an `Activity`. The idea is that the user needs to be in control of what pops onto his screen. If he taps a notification, he expects that something will appear on his screen, if your `Service` launches an `Activity`, that can happen at any time and could possibly interrupt him.

Comment: Thank you David! I had a question specific for the android 12 tramplione replacement: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71260031/android-12-how-replace-the-notification-trampolines`, if you could put your thought there I will take it as answer and close that one.